# 青いの本はここです or ここに青いの本があります

Tags: grammar

1. "Aoi no hon wa koko desu." (A blue book here, is) or
2. "Koko ni aoi no hon ga arimasu." (Here a blue book is)

Is one MORE correct than the other? Is one more casual, and the other formal? Is one COMPLETELY wrong?

Feel free to give other examples as well, even "imasu" examples of animate objects.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. 「青いの本わここです。」

should be

> 1. 「青い本はここです。」

The の particle isn't necessary when an adjective is modifying a noun.

> 2. 「ここに青いの本があります。」

should be

> 2. 「ここに青い本があります。」

You were pretty close to perfect, although the の still isn't necessary.

I'd say the two phrases mean the exact same thing, but how they might come about would be different. So if someone asked 「青い本はどこですか？」, you'd reply with the first sentence. But if they asked 「そこに何がありますか？」, you'd reply with the second.

Comment: When you say "の is not necessary" do you mean: "It is still correct, but hey, why go through the trouble unless youn are trying to explain it to a beginner"? Or did you mean: "NO! Don't EVER do it that way for any reason at all!" ? Is there a difference for casual/formal/honorific speach? (Besides ある and いる being more casual than あります and います , I mean.)

Comment: @Ronk You can't use の with i-adjectives. 青いの本 is wrong. You can write 青の本 though. Some of the colours (red, blue, white, black) have a form where you drop the い and use の.

Comment: No, the phrases do not mean the exact same thing, the first has a definite article whereas the second is indefinite. 1 means "The blue book is here." whereas 2 means "There is a blue book here." That is why they are not interchangeable in the example questions you wrote.